# How does the length of list predicate work

Tags: list, prolog

I know there are some topics already about this. But I still dont get it.

Could be somebody describe step by step how:

```
length1([],0).
length1([X|Xs],N) :-length1(Xs,M), N is M+1.
```

works? I put traces on but I still have no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through an example:

```
?- length1([a, b, c], N).
```

First Prolog tries to unify with the first rule, but `[a, b, c]` doesn't match `[]`. So it tries to unify with the second rule, and we get:

```
length1([a|[b, c]], N) :-
    length1([b, c], M), % We do this first
    N is M + 1.  % We can't solve this yet because we don't know what M is
```

So we've matched [a, b, c] to [a|[b,c]], which is part of the list syntax. We can't work out what N is yet, but we've got to do the middle line first, which unifies with the same rule:

```
length1([b|[c]], M) :-
     length1([c], L),
     M is L + 1.
```

As before, we need to do the middle line to work out what M is.

```
length1([c|[]], L) :-
    length1([], K),
    L is K + 1.
```

We still can't work it out, but now our middle line unifies with the first rule:

```
length1([], 0).  % So now we know what K is!
```

We've unified K with 0, so now we can start going back up:

```
length1([c|[]], 1) :-
    length1([], 0),
    1 is 0 + 1. % L is K + 1

length1([b|[c]], 2) :-
     length1([c], 1),
     2 is 1 + 1. % M is L + 1

length1([a|[b, c]], 3) :-
    length1([b, c], 2), 
    3 is 2 + 1. % N is M + 1
```

So we exit our recursion with N unified to 3:

```
?- length1([a, b, c], N).
N = 3.
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I was looking for. I still struggle a bit with the "N is M+1" syntax. More in general: How is the "is-Operator" unified?

Comment: `is/2` evaluates the mathematical expression on the RHS and unifies the result with the left. It's more of a function than a predicate. Try `?- X = 1 + 1, Y = X + 1.` and compare it to `?- X = 1 + 1, Y is X + 1`. You can carry expressions around before evaluating them in Prolog. This is useful to distinguish 2 bags of 5 cookies from 5 bags of 2 cookies. 2*5 and 5*2 may both be 10 but they're very different when you want to share cookies between 5 people.

Comment: Works the part after "We've unified K with 0, so now we can start going back up:" like in other programm languages with the stack? So we have for each recursion a new stack frame which is processed, or what is happening? I understand the logic, but still dont understand what technically is happening...Thanks! I am also confused about "going back up" what is the  meaning of that?

Comment: Yes, going back through the stack frames, there's no tail call optimization in this definition.

Answer (score 1):

List-processing predicates in Prolog are almost always going to have two clauses, because the list type is defined inductively as:

> A list is either:
>
> - Empty: `[]`, or
> - An item, plus a list: `[X|Xs]`

Inductive data structures often have predicates whose definitions break down into the same cases as the structure itself. In the case of length, the inductive definition looks like:

> The length of a list is either:
>
> - 0 for empty lists, or
> - 1 + the length of the rest of the list

And that's exactly what you have here in the Prolog code:

```
length1([], 0).
```

says that the length of the empty list is zero. This is your base case. A better second clause would be:

```
length1([_|Xs], N1) :- length1(Xs, N), N1 is N+1
```

This says, supposing you have a list with some item (we don't care about what it is) and a tail of a list, the length of this list is N1, where N1 is 1 + the length of the tail of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It works badly. Here is how it is supposed to work:

```
?- length([], N).
N = 0.

?- length([_,_], N).
N = 2.

?- length(L, 0).
L = [].

?- length(L, 2).
L = [_5494, _5500].

?- length(L, N).
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [_5524],
N = 1 ;
L = [_5524, _5530],
N = 2 .

?- L = [_|L], length(L, N).
ERROR: Type error: `list' expected, found `@(S_1,[S_1=[_6396|S_1]])' (a cyclic)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] throw(error(type_error(list,...),context(...,_6460)))
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

... and here is how the version from your question works:

```
?- length1([], N).
N = 0. % OK

?- length1([_,_], N).
N = 2. % OK

?- length1(L, 0).
L = [] ; % does not terminate!
^CAction (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
?- length1(L, 2).
L = [_9566, _9572] ; % does not terminate
^CAction (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
?- length1(L, N).
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [_9602],
N = 1 ;
L = [_9602, _9608],
N = 2 . % OK

?- L = [_|L], length1(L, N).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1.0Gb, global: 37Kb, trail: 1Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 11,180,538, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 3
ERROR:   Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
ERROR:     [11,180,538] user:length1([cyclic list], _9792)
ERROR:     [11,180,537] user:length1([cyclic list], _9818)
```

The last one looks the same, but the built-in `length/2` throws a type error instead of exceeding the stack.

There is another problem with `length1/2`, it uses up the stack if the list is too long, because every recursive step must be left on the stack with the current definition.

```
?- length(L, 10 000 000). % make a long list, works
L = [_984, _990, _996, _1002, _1008, _1014, _1020, _1026, _1032|...].

?- length(L, 10 000 000), length(L, N). % how long is the long list?
L = [_1258, _1264, _1270, _1276, _1282, _1288, _1294, _1300, _1306|...],
N = 10000000.

?- length(L, 10 000 000), length1(L, N). % how long is the list? too long!
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.5Gb, global: 0.2Gb, trail: 1Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 5,592,186, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 3
ERROR:   Possible non-terminating recursion:
ERROR:     [5,592,186] user:length1([length:4,407,825], _60000944)
ERROR:     [5,592,185] user:length1([length:4,407,826], _60000970)
```

Moreover:

```
?- time( length(L, 1 000) ).
% 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 46417 Lips)
L = [_886, _892, _898, _904, _910, _916, _922, _928, _934|...].

?- time( length(L, 10 000) ).
% 2 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (99% CPU, 3495 Lips)
L = [_888, _894, _900, _906, _912, _918, _924, _930, _936|...].

?- time( length1(L, 1 000) ).
% 501,499 inferences, 0.067 CPU in 0.067 seconds (100% CPU, 7511131 Lips)
L = [_878, _884, _890, _896, _902, _908, _914, _920, _926|...] .

?- time( length1(L, 10 000) ).
% 50,014,999 inferences, 4.938 CPU in 4.941 seconds (100% CPU, 10128365 Lips)
L = [_876, _882, _888, _894, _900, _906, _912, _918, _924|...] .
```

It takes too long to make bigger lists using `length1/2` so this is why I am showing it with such a short list. But you might notice that a list 10 times longer makes your `length1/2` run 100 times longer. You should ask whoever showed you this code what that means.

Why am I writing this? Not sure. I think it is irresponsible to show students shitty code. On the other hand, this is a popular question (in the sense that many people before you have asked the exact same thing).

Comment: Thank you for that info! Works "length" internally (in general) the same like my "length1" or is it totally different?

Comment: Totally different, and totally different from anything you'll find in a textbook, [here's the SWI-Prolog implementation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/boot/init.pl?show=src#length/2), you can view the source of most predicates in their docs.

Comment: @rene As the other comment says, you can read the implementation of at least SWI-Prolog, GNU-Prolog, and YAP (all three are open-source). But what you need to do at the very least, you need to handle the different cases (get length of list and generate list of length) separately.

Comment: @PaulBrown "Totally different" is a bit of an exaggeration. Look at `$length3/3` at the bottom of what you linked ;-)